# function doesn't recognize pattern-matching

Tags: haskell

My function `paralellenCheck` throws an exception everytime I call it complaining about Non-exhaustive patterns

`paralellenCheck` is defined as follows:

```
paralellenCheck :: (Eq a, Num a ) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
paralellenCheck [] [] = True
paralellenCheck [_] [] = True
paralellenCheck [] [_] = True
paralellenCheck (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | intervall `elem`  [0,5,7,12]  = False
  | not $ paralellenCheck (x:xs) ys  = False 
  | not $ paralellenCheck xs (y:ys)  = False
  | otherwise  = True
  where intervall = abs (x - y)
```

running the function in GHCI with -Wall applied just returns

```
<interactive>:10:1:
Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Integer'
           (Eq a0)
             arising from a use of `paralellenCheck' at <interactive>:10:1-15
           (Num a0)
             arising from a use of `paralellenCheck' at <interactive>:10:1-15
In the expression: paralellenCheck [] [2, 3, 4, 5]
In an equation for `it': it = paralellenCheck [] [2, 3, 4, ....]

<interactive>:10:1:
Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type `Integer'
           (Eq a0)
             arising from a use of `paralellenCheck' at <interactive>:10:1-15
           (Num a0)
             arising from a use of `paralellenCheck' at <interactive>:10:1-15
In the expression: paralellenCheck [] [2, 3, 4, 5]
In an equation for `it': it = paralellenCheck [] [2, 3, 4, ....]
*** Exception: haskelltest.hs:(6,1)-(14,31): Non-exhaustive patterns in function paralellenCheck
```

I am rather new to haskell and rather confused. I thought the pattern-matching with `[_] []` and `[] [_]` should resolve this issue.

Comment: Try replacing your `[_]` with just `_`. Also, you might want to supply your definitions for `(x:xs) (y:ys)` first, and then supply a `_ _ = True` pattern afterwards.

Comment: wouldn't this destroy the recursion though? every new recursion would start a new one before having the chance to cancel by `_ _`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[_]` in a pattern means "any list of exactly one element". You seem to have intended "any list at all". Right now, `[] (a:b:[])`, for example, is not matched. Use `_` for any list.

Comment: wouldn't this destroy the recursion though? every new recursion would start a new one before having the chance to cancel by `_ _ ` 

also, Thank you very much ^^

Comment: Just to make it more clear: you have patterns for both empty lists, one list empty, another of length 1, and both lists of length of at least 1. What is missing is a pattern for one list empty, another longer than 1.

Comment: @9000 so [_] does not cover all cases for a list with arbitrary many cases? what would such a check look like? would `_` cover all cases for such a list?

Comment: @user3763118: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I *think* what you might be getting at is: the first matching mattern is the one that will be used. As long as the (x:xs) (y:ys) pattern is defined first, then you'll have no problem.

EDIT: and in response to your second comment, yes; that's exactly what my answer says.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield So when `xs` or `ys` are the empty list, then `x:xs` and `y:ys` are not matching patterns and the other cases are tried. This makes sense. Thanks! ^^